# Floor division in go

Tags: python, go, math

I'm translating some old come from Python to Go. In this code, I used the floor division with the floor operator in Python.

```py
d = b // c
# (c isn't a comment, I use the // operator from python)
```

My problem is, this operator doesn't exist in Go. What's the easiest way to translate in Go?

Comment: If `c` is a power of 2, you can use a right shift (`>>`).

Comment: What do you know about the signs of `b` and `c`? Is `c` always positive? Is `b` always nonnegative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `b` and `c` are integers, `b / c` is already the floor division. If they are float64s, use `math.Floor(b/c)`. If using float32 (or any other numeric type), you must convert first: `math.Floor(float64(b)/float64(c))`

Comment: `b/c` isn't floor division, it's round-towards-zero division. `(-1)//2` is -1 in python, `(-1)/2` is 0 in go.